# How to program the navigation bar(image) web html

Tags: html, css

may I know how do I program the seemingly simple navigation bar in the attached image of the pied piper website in the show "silicon valley" in HTML/CSS? In particular, how do one program the dark blue portion?

Do I attach a dark blue image and have its position set to "absolute" and have the link buttons and logos placed on top of it?

Or is it any other better way?

Thank you!!

[image: picture]

Comment: What "dark blue portion"? There is only black, white and green...

Comment: I think he's referring to the black background. It actually is rgb(3, 10, 24) :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or is it any other better way?

Are you really asking how to set a background (color) with CSS?

You should have a look at [the w3 tutorial about CSS backgrounds](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp) then.

Just have a `div` and apply a dark blue background with CSS like

```
div.whatever-class-you-choose
{
    background: rgb(3, 10, 24);
}
```

Or check out [the fiddle I made](http://jsfiddle.net/L8xfopcc/2/). It's all pretty self-explaining.

Comment: Thanks @Siguza! May I know what is the meaning of the CSS tag `nav > div` though?

Comment: (Notice that it's `.nav > div`, the `.` is important.) "A div element that is a direct child of an element with the class `nav`."

Comment: Hi @Siguza, just wondering, why is it that if we use `.nav > div` and set a `float` tag under it, the position of the links will be different as opposed to if we just set a `float`tag under `.nav ul` element? Thanks.

Comment: Because there is no `ul` element at all?

Comment: So suppose I use a `ul` tag followed by a `li`tag and under it have it set as `in-line` and `float: right` in CSS, why is the position different from `.nav>div` when they are supposedly the similar? Sorry for my really amateur question! Also, may i know why is your logo not affected by the white background that is usually apparent if you use a image from google and that it blends seamlessly into the background? Thanks!

Comment: I have no idea what you're doing, but [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ujzztwbz/) I used `ul` and `li` and it looks the same to me, pixel for pixel. Also, that **is** just an image I found on Google, it only happens to have a transparent background instead of a white one. ^^